# How to decode WorPress PHP virus file?

Tags: php, wordpress, decode, malware

My WordPress site infected with some malware files , found lot of files like below, 
I tried to decode that using some online decoders, but no luck. I want to know what hacker do using this file.

I guess he control some more files on my sites but scanner only detect this code, by decode this hope to find other file paths

Paths of file found are given below

```
wp-includes/rest-api/requests.ini
wp-includes/Requests/IPconfig.ini
```

below have little part of file

**Here have full file in pastebin** https://pastebin.com/EfUNTaRr

```
if(empty($_GET['ineedthispage'])){
ini_set('display_errors',"Off");
ignore_user_abort(1);
$I7rKRVNNat3intmYmv="10.1";
$IssgsfYr3WZGty="";
$IL8lxLZy5SGibS7od="";
$IGvpZBegv061k="";
if(!empty($_COOKIE['PHPSSIDDD2'])){
    $IGvpZBegv061k=$_COOKIE['PHPSSIDDD2'];
    }
    $IvVtGi5vH1edafW="RE3PUldBWUlTV4";
    if(!IIlFCqjaR5JVZ33VAo('curl_init')){
        $IssgsfYr3WZGty.="1\t";
        $IL8lxLZy5SGibS7od.="1\t";
    }
    if(!IIlFCqjaR5JVZ33VAo('fopen')){
```

can someone decode that file on paste bin. Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted this questions, without any explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used phpcs-fixer for some pretty view of this script. You can see it [here](https://pastebin.com/VqKNN9h0). I don't spend much time for decoding, so I can be wrong in my reasoning =)

Function `IIlFCqjaR5JVZ33VAo` is like improved `function_exists` which check if function exists and is callable and not disabled (get from ini)

```
function __function_exists($functionName)
{
    $functionName=strtolower(trim($functionName));
    if ($functionName=='') {
        return false;
    }
    $disabledFunctions=explode(",", @ini_get("disable_functions"));
    if (empty($disabledFunctions)) {
        $disabledFunctions=array();
    } else {
        $disabledFunctions=array_map('trim', array_map('strtolower', $disabledFunctions));
    }
    return (function_exists($functionName) && is_callable($functionName) && !in_array($functionName, $disabledFunctions));
}
```

Script collect many things in files. File names encoded by this rules:

```
// this is like file hash
$ItZg0lwPNAV8rSZCcknwRw6=md5(__FILE__);
// ... some other stuff and define directory like {path_to_file}/cache{file_hash}
$Id3jh7jnThGJnxV0=dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."cache".$ItZg0lwPNAV8rSZCcknwRw6;
// and then file stored in defined dir
$Id3jh7jnThGJnxV1=$Id3jh7jnThGJnxV0.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."ke".substr($ItZg0lwPNAV8rSZCcknwRw6, 0, 8)."ys";
// and so on for [keys, useragents, botips, referers, ...] with interesting logic which I don'tfully understand
```

And then some data sends to `http://main.infowp.info/getdata.php`. But I'm not sure. Why this domain? You can see it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28bd91e873b95839b01b174c19bb454dde4a59cc)

And it determines which CMS used: WP, Drupal or Joomla by check if specific function and class exists: wp_insert_post, node_save, JFactory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer infowp.info is a Russian site, hacker seems like Russian guy, but i'm still not sure what he oing with site because he didn't  one any harm on surface

Comment: In general, it was a superficial assessment. I think that the script is not so innocuous, because at first glance it collects pretty important data.
I would recommend to look at the access logs. Then block access to the specified domain. And, of course, do not be lazy and thoroughly examine the script. Yes, maybe it takes quite a lot of time. I saw that script search something on google, yahoo and bing, add metatags, registering globals, save files (and maybe delete after processing). In many ways the usual search and replace will help. Then the logic of work will be visible in more detail.

Comment: thanks i found the mole, it's uploaded via WordPress cherry framework plugin, which had individual upload php script, https://whatisgon.wordpress.com/2015/07/16/cleaning-up-cherryframeworks-malware-installer/

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted this questions, without any explanation

Comment: @SunethKalhara I have been using Stackerflow for quite long time. But until recently I was only looking for answers and did not pay attention to ratings, and other social garbage (imho). And just as I decided to answer a couple of questions, I saw that something was amiss was going on here. I do not know why minus. Probably because they facing this everyday?))